# How to get value of hidden filed which is set in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a hidden field. When user click on a button (here delete button) its value is set is as one in java script.Now I want to get its value on posting the input field - submit .
My code is here.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="clicked_delete_btn"  id="clicked_delete_btn" value=""/>
 <input type="button" name='delete' id='delete' value="Delete" onClick="return confirm_delete(this);"> 
 <input type="submit" name="update" value="UPDATE"  >
```

javascript

```
function confirm_deleteo(ele) {
    if (confirm('Do you wish to delete the file?')) {
        ele.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('clicked_delete_btn').value = 1;
        return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

php code

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $delete_clicked=$_POST['clicked_delete_btn'];
    if($delete_clicked==1) {
        //do operations
    }
}
```

But it's value is not getting on $_POST['update'].

Comment: Get ELEMENTBYID !!! in the confirm delete you must use getElementById("clicked_photo_delete_btn")

Comment: `clicked_photo_delete_btn != clicked_delete_btn` it seems you messed up with name and ID

Comment: sorry. please check my code now. it is clicked_delete_btn

Comment: Are you for sure sending form by POST?

Comment: yes using method="POST"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ID instead of name

```js
document.getElementById('clicked_photo_delete_btn').value = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to assemble your code and it works fine on my system:

http://pastebin.com/NAEYAZre, http://pastebin.com/3vEsrHJJ

Check your form tag options.

Comment: kind of a comment, but I won't down vote because it is barely that way. Try to be a little more informative on answers like this one or just write them as a comment.